# exclude top navigation from sharepoint search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, navigation, crawl

How do i exclude top navigation in sharepoint 2010  site from being seen by SharePoint search. I have tried adding noindex class to the control as below but it doesn't work.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderHorizontalNav" runat="server">
                    <SharePoint:AspMenu
                      ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
                      Runat="server"
                      EnableViewState="false"
                      DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
                      AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
                      UseSimpleRendering="true"
                      UseSeparateCss="false"
                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                      StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                      MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1"
                      SkipLinkText=""
                      CssClass="s4-tn noindex"/>
                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">
                        <Template_Controls>
                            <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                              ShowStartingNode="False"
                              SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                              id="topSiteMap"
                              runat="server"
                              StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
                        </Template_Controls>
                    </SharePoint:DelegateControl>

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

the control adds another nested div with class 'menu-horizontal' to which also i add the 'noindex' class but still Search brings up all the pages if I search for like "About us" as "About us" is in the top nav.

Doesn anyone know how to hide the top nav from SharePoint search?

Comment: Looks like you are doing it right. Have you reset the search index after making the change? If not then I suggest you to reset the search index or simply delete and then recreate the content source and run a full crawl.

Comment: check out the below link . . .
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2011/01/26/how-to-exclude-part-of-a-page-from-being-indexed-by-sharepoint-search.aspx